# Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap crash on configuration change of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bitmap, android-orientation

I have a listview inside a fragment. Each row of the listview has imageview and I'm loading bitmap image. I set the bitmap as a tag to the imageview. Next time when the image view with non-null tag is encountered, I'm recycling the bitmap in the tag and reloading image into it. This is causing crash "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap" crash when the orientation of the activity is changed. I couldn't figure out why this is happening. Please help.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) imageView.getTag();
    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
    Ion.with(appContext)
            .load(uri)
            .asBitmap()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                        imageView.setTag(result);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Stack trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@31a3918
                                                                                      at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1270)
                                                                                      at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1404)
                                                                                      at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:544)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1228)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16184)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3418)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2615)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3413)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16187)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4166)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15180)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15954)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15140)
                                                                                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
                                                                                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
                                                                                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.

Comment: can you bit clarify your question? Ion will takes the uri to get the image from internal memory or server and set to image view. I think I am not sure the crash is related to bitmap recycling. Please paste your full log trace here

Comment: Loading bitmaps was causing OutOfMemory crash for me. So, I wanted to free the memory used by bitmap (which was already assigned to an imageview) whenever a new image has to be loaded into the imageview. But, this is causing a crash when the orientation of the activity changes from portrait to landscape. I have added the stack trace in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) imageView.getTag();
        if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
           // bitmap.recycle();

 Ion.with(appContext)
                .load(uri)
                .asBitmap()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                            imageView.setTag(result);
                        }
                    }
                });

        }


Try this.
```

Comment: The image in the uri could have changed. So, I need to load from the uri everytime. I thought freeing the memory used by the previous bitmap would help me avoid OutOfMemory crash.